# In Flutter, as the width of the listView I have increases, I want the sheet to increase in size

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable, flutter-animation

```dart
return AnimatedContainer(
      height: _containerHeight,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          const SheetIndicatorComponent(),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              reverse: true,
              controller: _scrollControllerListView,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 1,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: CSizes.triplePadding, horizontal: CSizes.triplePadding * 2),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: containerHeight,
                            width: containerWidth,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: CColors.positive.withOpacity(.1),
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: CSizes.triplePadding),
                            child: ShaderMask(
                              blendMode: BlendMode.srcIn,
                              shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) => const LinearGradient(
                                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                stops: [.2, 1],
                                colors: [
                                  CColors.realPositive,
                                  CColors.pink,
                                ],
                              ).createShader(bounds),
                              child: const Icon(
                                MaterialIcons.bubble_chart,
                                size: iconSize,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Co-Pilot",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                              fontSize: CSizes.large,
                              fontWeight: CWeights.bolder,
                              fontFamily: CFonts.proDisplay,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      PaginatedChatBuilder(
                        service: BotMessagingService(
                          null,
                          hiddenTypes: [
                            MessageTypes.satisfactionQuestion,
                            MessageTypes.portfolioAnalysis,
                            MessageTypes.botStockData,
                          ],
                        )..sendMessage(
                            widget.prompt,
                            null,
                            MessageTypes.text,
                            null,
                          ),
                        onSwipedMessage: null,
                        scrollController: _scrollControllerPaginatedChatBuilder,
                        showMessageTime: false,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          DividerWithoutPadding(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: CSizes.triplePadding,
            ),
            color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light ? CColors.lightDivider : CColors.darkDivider,
          ),
          const ChatBotRouteButton(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

I tried the `DraggableScrollableSheet` widget but it didn't work. I want the sheet to grow as the `PaginatedChatBulilder` grows